# How to restrict access to Selenium Standalone Server instance?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-server

I have an instance of Selenium Standalone server in a virtual Widows box to run my tests on. It's being started in the following way:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -D"webdriver.chrome.driver"=chromedriver_2.13.exe -D"webdriver.ie.driver"=IEDriverServer_2.44.exe
```

Today I've noticed in the output some unexpected lines. The tests are running in the night and after that I see following:

> 08:46:20.197 INFO - Couldn't proxy to http://www.cv7.waw.pl/108258/Dachy/artykul.html because host not found
>
> 11:12:07.873 INFO - Couldn't proxy to http://g1nkaku.bieszczady.pl/damy-rade-zespol-na-wesele-bydgoszcz because host not found
>
> 11:49:49.204 INFO - Couldn't proxy to http://www.swiat.opt.waw.pl/Kryszyn/planeta-102-7/ because host not found

None of my tests were accessing any of such links, especially at these timestamps, and I have no idea where it can come from. My assumption is that someone found out the link to this instance of Selenium server and was sending requests through it.

What are my options to restrict access to Selenium server? Are there any options to request some custom login/password for all clients of this server? It's being used by several people in our team from multiple locations, so IP based checks are not an option.